# Правильный редирект htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Старый сайт содержал ссылки вида http://xxx.com/ru/article. Новый сайт содержит ту же информацию, но вид ссылок http://xxx.com/article без ru/. Как правильно прописать редирект в htaccess, чтобы перенаправить все страницы нового вида по старым адресам?(оба сайта на joomla, возможно есть какие -либо инструменты движка)

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/ru/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
попробуй

Comment: ничего не изменилось(((

Comment: Какая версия Joomla?

Comment: Версия Joomla! 3.6.5

Comment: код если можно покажите

Comment: Код htaccess? Там был стандартный джумловский и я просто вставила Ваш код туда. Я так понимаю, тот код что Вы дали -он убирает ру в линке. А мне нужно наоборот добавлять. Но так:  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ru/$2 [R=301,L] не работает совсем.

Comment: vov4ok забыл закрыть строку (символ $) `RewriteRule ^(.*)/ru/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$2 [R=301,L]`

Comment: @DNS не получалось  меня Ваш вариант -на404 выбрасывало, вот так вроде идет: RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ http://xxx.com/$1 [R=301,L]